# Simple script - automatic loading to a sqlite file / database

Tags: shell, sqlite, batch-file

I would like to automate the loading of data into the sqlite database file.
How to do it so that each line will do when the previous one ends?

Can I do it with a .bat or .ps1 file?

```
sqlite3 path\test.db
DELETE * FROM sales;
.mode csv
.import path2\sales.csv sales_tmp
INSERT INTO sales select * from sales_tmp;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sales_tmp;
vacuum;
.quit
```

Comment: With a unix style shell, you can use a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) for the commands to sqlite3. Not sure what the equivalent is in Windows-land, though.

Comment: Putting all your commands into a txt file, then `sqlite3 path\to\test.db < scriptfile.txt` works for me.

Comment: It does not work for me - I do not know how I should do it.
When do I know all the commands have been done?

The point is that each subsequent command should be activated only when the previous one ends.

Comment: Also, `type scriptfile.txt | sqlite3 path\to\test.db` appears to work.  But yeah, the input redirection method should block line-by-line.  You could insert a `select` line in between lines to output statuses if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlite3 path\test.db^
 -cmd "DELETE FROM sales;"^
 -cmd ".mode csv"^
 -cmd "CREATE TABLE sales_tmp (col1, col2);"^
 -cmd ".import 'path2\sales.csv' 'sales_tmp'"^
 -cmd "INSERT INTO sales SELECT * FROM sales_tmp;"^
 -cmd "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sales_tmp;"^
 -cmd "vacuum;"^
 ""
```

`-cmd COMMAND` will run `COMMAND` before reading stdin.

The `^` at end of lines is a continuation character so can avoid a long command line.

You do need to create the `sales_tmp` table before importing the data, so I added
the table creation statement. Adjust column names as needed.

The `""` at the end is the sql statement, which if empty, allows `sqlite3` to exit.
If you omit the argument, then it goes to interactive mode.

For command line help with `sqlite3`, type `sqlite3 --help` at a `cmd` prompt.

For interactive help with `sqlite3`, type `.help` at the interactive `sqlite3` prompt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
However, I can not do it as directed.


You do need to create the sales_tmp table before importing the data, so I added the table creation statement. Adjust column names as needed.
-> This is not necessary, SQLite will create a table with headings - that's what this is about.

These commands pasted into the .bat file do not work.

Comment: These commands work exactly the way I want them when I type them (one after the other) in CMD. I just want it to be done automatically after running the script / file.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in powershell:

```
Write-Output @"
DELETE * FROM sales;
.mode csv
.import path2/sales.csv sales_tmp
INSERT INTO sales SELECT * FROM sales_tmp;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sales_tmp;
VACUUM;
.quit
"@ | sqlite3 test.db
```

(Uses a Powershell dialect herestring as described in my earlier link in a comment about heredocs)

Comment: But it's an option!

Comment: @Qlikeers I copied & pasted from your question without bothering to actually look at the sql. Yeah, that's a syntax error.